# Is using AngularJS and WebApi good for large complex systems? Questions also

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-ui

We currently have an asp.net webforms web application, which needs updating in terms of look and speed.  I think its time to redevelop it and was thinking about creating a webApi and change the website to asp mvc.  But then i started using AngularJS and loved it, now i am thinking about redeveloping our site using AngularJs and a webApi.

Am i right in thinking that using AngularJs + ASP MVC is pointless, as they are nearly the same thing (although 1 is clientside and 1 is server side)

Also i have a couple questions about using angularJs on a website.

1. On the mobile apps that i have used angularJS i have used the routeProvider and stateProvider to change the page.  This adds #/SOMETHING to the url and angular loads the correct content accordingly.  Does this work ok with search engines like google?
2. Should the whole web application be 1 app within angular, or should it be broken down into app modules and each be a separate "app", even though it is 1 website?  I am wondering about performance.  Say i have a website where the user can look at companies, contacts, projects.  Each module may have 10 different pages, can angular handle this?  In our app we would have over 20 modules, each with maybe 10 pages+.
3. Is this something i should avoid?  Would ASP MVC + webApi be better?

Any other views and opinions are greatly welcome, i want to get as much information as possible before making my decision and developing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to address some of your concerns.

ASP.Net Partial views can still be used even if you decide to use AngularJS and WebAPI. Have a server view has some advantages. For example if your view has element that are only accessible to authorize users in a specific role, then better to not emit that view content from server, rather than hiding it on client side using AngularJS.

I have not done mobile development using AngularJS so i cannot answer your bullet point 1. But as far as SEO goes every client side framework has the same challenge. Google `SEO techniques` for Angular and you may find something interesting.

Regarding bullet 2, all depends. Multiple SPA apps can be created if the functionality is tangential. For example user side of app and admin side of the app can be different SPA but they can be a single SPA too. I think it all depends upon on scenario and there is no hard and fast rule.

For bullet 3, this is too broad question. I can only say AngularJS is a very capable framework and can do everything that MVC+ WebApi can achieve. There is a learning curve involved and it takes some time to do stuff the Angular way but i believe it is well worth.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If i use ASP.MVC + AngularJS, does my application get bootstrapped upon every server call/page change?  I have never dealt with server page calls with angular.

Comment: It is not server page call. Look at this VS template project http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cc6c9c5f-2846-4822-899f-a6c295cd4f2b/ for integrating MVC, WebAPI and AngularJS. This is a bare bone implementation that I have released. This should answer your questions.